# Understanding the Progress class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

As the title says, I would like to understand what the class `Progress<T>` is actually doing. One might guess that the following implementation has the same behavior:

```
class MyProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private Action<T> _handler;

    public MyProgress(Action<T> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        _handler?.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

In a single threaded program, we won't observe any difference between `Progress` and `MyProgress`. However, if we try using the `MyProgress` class in a WPF application to update a progress bar from a thread not owning the WPF form, we get a `InvalidOperationException`.

So it seems that `Progress.Report` does some magic to invoke the handler in its owning thread. What is the correct implementation of the `Report` method?

Comment: It is supposed to *avoid* an InvalidOperationException.  The not-so-obvious requirement is that you must call its constructor from code that runs on the main UI thread.  That way it can correctly copy SynchronizationContext.Current, allowing it to fire the ProgressChanged event back on the UI thread and avoid that exception.  Otherwise does the same thing as Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `SynchronizationContext` internally to call the method on SynchronizationContext thread which for WPF would be the UI thread.

Source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/progress.cs,5e92455af584587d,references